# Check whether a string contains one of multiple substrings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-2.1

I've got a long string-variable and want to find out whether it contains one of two substrings.

e.g.

```
haystack = 'this one is pretty long'
needle1 = 'whatever'
needle2 = 'pretty'
```

Now I'd need a disjunction like this which doesn't work in Ruby though:

```
if haystack.include? needle1 || haystack.include? needle2
    puts "needle found within haystack"
end
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try parens in the expression:

```
 haystack.include?(needle1) || haystack.include?(needle2)
```

Comment: Can't believe that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 105):

```
[needle1, needle2].any? { |needle| haystack.include? needle }
```

Comment: also works with .all? if you wanted AND logic instead of OR logic.  Thanks, seph!

Comment: this is the better answer if you need to be flexible with the amount of needles.  `needles = [obj1, obj2, ..., objN]; needles.any?  { |needle| haystack.include? needle }`

Answer (score 24):

You can do a regex match:

```
haystack.match? /needle1|needle2/
```

Or if your needles are in an array:

```
haystack.match? Regexp.union(needles)
```

(For Ruby < 2.4, use `.match` without question mark.)

Comment: Your code has a typo, it should be `match` no question mark.

Comment: @SephCordovano How am I using it wrong and how can I correct it? To me it looks exactly the same as the `match?` method documentation example linked above.

Comment: @SephCordovano your comment is confusing. You should either expand it or delete it.

Comment: @jj_What's confusing about it? If you want to search for an array of substrings you use a union.

Comment: Please check your Ruby version before commenting. 2.4.0 has `match?` whereas previous Ruby versions did not have this method. Added a caveat to the answer to help address some of the comments mentioned here.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Clean and scalable.

Answer (score 10):

```
(haystack.split & [needle1, needle2]).any?
```

To use comma as separator: `split(',')`

Answer (score 9):

For an array of substrings to search for I'd recommend

```
needles = ["whatever", "pretty"]

if haystack.match?(Regexp.union(needles))
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if contains at least one of two substrings:

```
haystack[/whatever|pretty/]
```

Returns first result found

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find simple way to search multiple substrings in an array and end up with below which answers the question as well. I've added the answer as I know many geeks consider other answers and not the accepted one only.

```
haystack.select { |str| str.include?(needle1) || str.include?(needle2) }
```

and if searching partially:

```
haystack.select { |str| str.include?('wat') || str.include?('pre') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` instead of `||`

```
if haystack.include? needle1 or haystack.include? needle2
```

`or` has lower presedence than `||` , or is "less sticky" if you will :-)

Comment: Using "or" instead of "||" is generally considered as a bad idea. No matter it will actually work in that specific case.
More info:
https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#andor-

and
https://graceful.dev/courses/the-freebies/modules/ruby-language/topic/episode-125-and-or/